# How is the Kolmogorov metric involving empirical CDFs calculated?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable, $\mathbf P_F$ and $\mathbf P_G$ be probability measures, $F(x)=\mathbf P_F(X\le x)$ and $G(x)=\mathbf P_G(X\le x)$ be cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) of $X$ under these probability measures, respectively. The Kolomogorov metric is defined as

$$d(F,G)=\sup_{x\in\mathbf R}|F(x)-G(x)|$$

Let $G$ be the empirical CDF of a sample $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$, i.e. $G(x)$ is the number of elements of the sequence less than or equal to $x$. It can also be expressed as an average of shifted step functions:

$$G(x)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nh(x-s_i)$$

where

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I would like to know how to calculate the metric when (1) $G$ is an empirical CDF (2) both $F$ and $G$ are empirical CDFs. Exploiting the property that CDFs are increasing, I came up with the following algorithms:

1. In an interval $[a,b)$ where $G$ is constant, the local supremum of $|F(x)-G(x)|$ is the maximum of $|F(a)-G(a)|$, $|F(b)-G(b)|$ and $|F(b)-\mathbf P_G(X<b)|$. The global supremum is the maximum of $|F(s_i)-G(s_i)|$ and $|F(s_i)-\mathbf P_G(X<s_i)|$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.
2. If $F$ and $G$ are empirical CDFs for samples $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_m$ and $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$, respectively, then $\sup_{x\in\mathbf R}|F(x)-G(x)|$ can be calculated by taking the maximum of $|F(r_i)-G(r_i)|$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $|F(s_j)-G(s_j)|$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I need help verifying if they are correct. I would also like to know if they generalize to higher dimensions, where a CDF is defined as $F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\mathbf P_F(X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2,\ldots,X_n\le x_n)$ and the Kolmogorov metric may be defined as

$$d(F,G)=\sup_{x\in\mathbf R^n}|F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)|$$